# HelloWorld program installation to the simulator, can't find program

Tags: android

Android SDK chose 2.3.3
AndroidManifest.xml file contents as follows

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="com.cyf.dialer"  
    android:versionCode="1"  
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">  

    <uses-sdk  
        android:minSdkVersion="8"  
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />  

    <application  
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"  
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">  
        <activity  
            android:name=".MainActivity"  
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >  
          </activity>  
    </application>  

</manifest>
```

app_name is：ChenyfDialer
in the manager can see the program in the simulation
[image]
But all procedures in the menu，cannot found
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the below intent filters to your Activity, like this,

```
 <activity  
            android:name=".MainActivity"  
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >  
       <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

For more clarification check this [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the intent filters in your menifest, you need to specify at least one activity with intent filters to launch your application, check following code.

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```